# Does the TurboGrafX16 store switches and/or flags in RAM?

Tags: memory-layout, turbografx-16, ram

Based the the specs I found for the TG16, it has 8 KB of RAM. I also found notes in the documentation of many opcodes that there is data stored in several "flags and switches" are these stored in RAM or in a designated register?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably referring to the status register. This is a hardware register in the CPU, and is not stored in RAM.

Generally speaking, the HuC6280 is similar to a 6502-family CPU. You may want to acquaint yourself better with those parts; familiarity with them will make the HuC6280 easier to understand.

Comment: I am looking the acquaint myself with those parts. where/how do i do that?

Comment: The 6502 was an extremely popular processor in its time. There were many books written about working with it. Read one.

Comment: @JackKasbrack It's a serious recommendation. Stack Exchange Q&A isn't a good medium to explain something this broad. A book is.